# How to use emacs to format my code?

Tags: emacs

I use the following in my .emacs for my c code formatting:

(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)

And I try to format my region by doing: M-x indent-region

But my code does not get formatted.

```
int    f1(int a, int b,    int c);
int f2();
```

f1 and f2 does not get aligned and there are extra space between 'int b' and int c', emacs does not format that for me

And 
struct mystruct{
   int   field1;
   int field2;
   int       field3;
}

none of the field are aligned after I do 'indent-region'

Can you please tell me how to get emacs c code formatting to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indent-region` only indents. It doesn't do full formatting or splitting lines. If you want more formatting options, try using something like [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

That emacs formatting applies to only the initial tab stops.  To pretty-print your code in other positions you'll need a different utility.